# Interfacing with USB devices in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to figure out how to interface with a USB device in Rust. Does anyone have a solution? I found a package called usb-rust, but it was deprecated.

Comment: As listed in `rust-usb`'s README: https://github.com/dcuddeback/libusb-rs

Comment: What have you tried? Asking for suggestions for libraries is [off topic of SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of wrappers to the C libusb library, including [libusb](https://github.com/dcuddeback/libusb-rs) and [usb](https://github.com/kevinmehall/rust-usb) I haven't used either yet, but since your question came up first in my search, I thought I'd log these two answers here.

Editing in 2022, neither libusb-rs, rust-usb have been updated to the current version of Rust, but as another answer points out, [rusb](https://lib.rs/crates/rusb) is very much active, builds libusb as part of installation, and wraps resources so they automatically get closed via RAII. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

I tried to use the [usb](https://crates.io/crates/usb) and [libusb](https://crates.io/crates/libusb) crates, but couldn't get my program to build correctly with the VS 2019 toolchain. [rusb](https://crates.io/crates/rusb) seems to have (roughly?) the same interface but downloads and builds *libusb* automatically, which worked for me without additional configuration.